# self.cleaned_data.get not working with integer field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a pretty basic definition within my forms.py to pull data from my submitted form. Something I have done with other apps, but for some reason, it is not working at the moment. I feel like I'm overlooking something. Whenever I `print(image_height)` I get `None`.

**models.py**

```
height_field = models.IntegerField(default=1200)
```

**forms.py**

```
    class PostForm(ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ['user', 'title', 'content', 'post_image', 
                     'height_field', 'width_field', 'draft', 'publish']

        def clean_post_image(self):
            post_image = self.cleaned_data["post_image"]
            image_height = self.cleaned_data.get("height_field")
            print(image_height)


            return post_image
```

Comment: print the form before calling `form.is_valid()` to see what is coming from the template

Comment: So by messing around a bit more, it turns out that because `height_field` occurs after `post_image` it cannot pull data from a field that occurs after it. That seems weird. When I put `height_field` before `image_field`  within the the `fields` list, it works...I vaguely remember this rule, but there has to be a way to avoid this. It seems really impractical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate your form field with respect to other field, you should do that in your clean method.

From the docs,

> The form subclass’s clean() method can perform validation that requires access to multiple form fields. This is where you might put in checks such as “if field A is supplied, field B must contain a valid email address”. This method can return a completely different dictionary if it wishes, which will be used as the cleaned_data.

You could do something like this,

```
def clean(self, cleaned_data):
    post_image = cleaned_data.get("post_image")
    height_image = cleaned_data.get("height_image")
    #do_your_thing
    return cleaned_data
```